# Caterpillars and Leaves. Can we do better than O(n*c)?

Tags: algorithm, math

Found this question while preparing for interviews.

Suppose that some caterpillars start from the bottom and jump to the next leaf. They
eat the leaf before jumping to next. We are given an array which represents jump steps
made by caterpillars. If the array is [2,4,7], it means caterpillar[­0] will eat leaf 2,4,6..
caterpillar[­1] will eat leaf 4,8,12.. and caterpillar­[2] will eat 7,14,21...0 represents ground.
Calculate the number of uneaten leaves.

Let us assume that the caterpillar jumps to its next destination if the current leaf is eaten. This means, that if caterpillar[7] finds that leaf 28 is eaten, it will proceed to eat leaf 35.

Let c be the number of caterpillars and n be the number of leaves.

The obvious brute force solution is iterating over a bool array of size n for each caterpillar and mark it as true if eaten or false otherwise. It takes O(n*c) time. Can we do better?

Comment: Any leaf whose number is not a multiple of any of the numbers in the given array shall be left uneaten.

Comment: You might want to use the [inclusion-exclusion principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle)

Comment: @user1990169 Yes, I understand that the problem reduces to the statement you just gave. Then the question converts to what's the best way to find numbers that are not multiples of any of the number.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A caterpillar eats all multiple of its 'jump step' `j`, thus if it were alone, each caterpillar would eat `floor(n/j)` leaves.

Now you have got to figure out which leaves you have counted several times. For example if you count all leaves that are dividable by 2 for the first caterpillar, then you don't have to count any leaves for the second caterpillar, who jumps 4 by 4.

For two items, these numbers counted twice are the multiples of the [least common multiple](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_common_multiple) of both items, and there are `floor(n/lcm(j,j'))` of those.

Note that for three terms, if you do this computation, you might remove some items twice : let us take 28 in your example. It will be eaten by the caterpillar with jump step 7, but counted for both others (because 28 % 4 == 28 % 2 == 0), thus you need to add the multiples that were removed multiple times : `floor(n/lcm(j,j',j"))`

You can see a pattern here, it's [the inclusion-exclusion principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle). The general formula follows :

[image: inclusion-exclusion formula]

Let Aj be the leaves eaten by a caterpillar with jump step j (if it were alone). Then for J a set of several capterpillar jump sets, A<sub>J</sub> is the set of leaves eaten by all of these caterpillars.

[image: AJ is the intersection of the Aj where j is in J]

Let us also define the least common multiple of a set as the least common multiple of all the elements in the set, so we can write `lcm(J)`.

The [n] in the inclusion-exclusion formula is the set of considered caterpillar jumps, thus in your case `[2,4,7]`, and we iterate over all the subsets of it. `|J|` is the size of the subset, and |A<sub>J</sub>| is the size of the number of leaves that each caterpillar in J could eat, so we get |A<sub>J</sub>| = `floor(n/lcm(J))`.

You now have a sum of 2<sup>c</sup> terms *, since that is the numbers of subsets of the `c` caterpillars. Note that you can save some time by saving the least common multiples instead of recomputing them from scratch.

I leave writing the actual code "as exercise", as some like to say : it is basically iterating over subsets and computing least common multiples, then putting it all together in the sum above.

This gets you the total number of eaten leaves. Getting the uneaten ones from here is trivial.

---

If we do it on a small example (to be able to check), with 0 the ground, `1..24` the leaves, and `[2,3,4]` the caterpillar jump steps.

The only surviving leaves will be {1, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23} : removing all even numbers and all numbers dividable by 3. That is, we expect the answer to be 8.

- First round : subsets of size 1.

  - Caterpillar `j=2` would, alone, eat 24/2 = 12 leaves
  - Caterpillar `j=3` would, alone, eat 24/3 = 8 leaves
  - Caterpillar `j=4` would, alone, eat 24/4 = 6 leaves
- Second round : subsets of size 2.

  - Caterpillar `j=2` and `j=3` would both like to eat 24/6  = 4 leaves : {6, 12, 18, 24}
  - Caterpillar `j=3` and `j=4` would both like to eat 24/12 = 2 leaves : {12, 24}
  - Caterpillar `j=4` and `j=2` would both like to eat 24/4  = 6 leaves : all those eaten by `4` are targeted by `2`
- Third round : subsets of size 3 : all caterpillars together

  - They all would like to eat 24/lcm(2,3,4) = 24/12 = 2 leaves : {12, 24}.
- Final round : 12 + 8 + 6 - 4 - 2 - 6 + 2 = 26 - 12 + 2 = 16 leaves are eaten

So 24 - 16 = 8 leaves remain.

---

* of course this is a worst case scenario. Hopefully you will iterate over subsets of increasing sizes, and as soon as the least common multiple of a subset J is bigger than `n`, you can disregard all supersets of that J. In particular, if all the subsets of a size `k` have an lcm bigger than n, you can stop iterating.

Comment: Thanks. Upvoted. That seems a good solution for small values of c such that n*c > 2^c. However I'll leave the question open to see if there are other solutions that are not exponential in c.

Comment: O(2^c) is not as bad as it sounds. If n is big (`n>O(2^c)`), O(2^c) is better than O(n); if n is small, the footnote on the answer guarantees complexity O(n) (actually, I suspect, even better, but I am not sure). So, in any case, this algorithm is faster than O(n*c).

Answer (score 3):

This is in reference to O(n*c) algo that you mentioned. It's O(n logc) if you look closely.

A caterpillar eats all multiple of its 'jump step' j, thus if it were alone, each caterpillar would eat floor(n/j) leaves.

This complexity is bounded by:
n+n/2+n/3+...+n/c <= n log(c)

It won't make a difference as c is small but just pointing out :)

Check this link for implementation of [Inclusion-exclusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle%22Inclusion_Exclusion_principle%22) by Cimbali: [figure out Uneaten Leaves algorithm bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35148149/figure-out-uneaten-leaves-algorithm-bug)

**EDIT:** Here is the proof that the harmonic series is bounded by log(c). We use the inequality for lower limit of integration.

[image]

Comment: What is `c` in your equation? `n + n/2 + ... + n/c` is equalled `n(1 + 1/2 + ... + 1/c)` and `1 + 1/2 + ... + 1/c` is harmonic series, this series is divergent  series and doesn't exist any limit [Harmonic series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_(mathematics)). Please provide a prove for your derived formula.

Comment: c denotes the number of distinct steps or the number of caterpillars as mentioned in the ques.
I have added an edit mentioning the proof of the formula.

Answer (score 0):

This is just an optimization over the approach suggested by @cimbali's. From the array containing strides for caterpillar. You can remove the multiples of a stride value from that array to reduce the number of combinations found.

For example 24 leaves, and [2,3,4] the caterpillar jump steps.

- First step:
  Go through the strides array and remove multiples of 2. Since 4 is a multiple of 2. Remove 4 from the array
- Second step : subsets of size 1.
  Caterpillar j=2 would, alone, eat 24/2 = 12 leaves
  Caterpillar j=3 would, alone, eat 24/3 = 8 leaves
- Third step : subsets of size 2.
  Caterpillar j=2 and j=3 would both like to eat 24/6 = 4 leaves : {6, 12, 18, 24}

So 24 - 16 (12+8-4) = 8 leaves remain.

Answer (score 0):

The complexity can't be of O(N) or even O(N/K). My algorithm is of O(2^K), which is huge in itself but still acceptable. Even if I pass N = Long.MAX_VALUE, I get immediate results. Though if K is greater, the code may take time or the code may break when LCM of all jump values exceeds Long.MAX_VALUE.

To explain it, let's take A = {4, 5, 6} and N = 20.

We can count uneaten leaves are {1, 2, 3, 7, 9, 11, 13, 14, 17, 19} = 10

How can we get this result without counting?
N - (N / 4) - (N / 5) - (N / 6) + (N / 20) + (N / 12) + (N / 30) - N / 60
= 20 - 5 - 4 - 3 + 1 + 1 + 0 - 0 = 20 - 12 + 2 = 10

[Caterpillar Uneaten Leaves Problem](http://deepakmishra117.blogspot.com/2017/09/caterpillar-uneaten-leaves-problem.html)

Answer (score 0):

It may be O(c^2) time which is better if c < n

```
public class JumpingCaterpillars {
  public static int getUneatenCount(int n, int... steps) {

    //no steps i.e. no caterpillars
    if(steps.length == 0){
      return n;
    }

    Arrays.sort(steps);

    if(steps[0] <= 0){
      throw(new IllegalArgumentException("steps should be positive"));
    }

    //all leaves will be eaten
    if(steps[0] == 1){
      return 0;
    }

    //remove duplicates and multiplies
    LinkedHashSet<Integer> normalizeSteps = new LinkedHashSet<>();

    for(int step : steps){
      if(!isMultiply(step, normalizeSteps)) {
        normalizeSteps.add(step);
      }
    }

    int nonEaten = n;

    for(int step : normalizeSteps){
      nonEaten -= getEatenWithStep(n, step);
    }

    /* increase nonEaten number considering caterpillar coincidences on the same leaf
    (when one caterpillar with step stepOne makes it times equal to another caterpillar stepTwo
    and vice versa)*/
    for(int stepOne : normalizeSteps){
      for(int stepTwo : normalizeSteps){
        if(stepOne < stepTwo){
          nonEaten += getEatenWithStep(n, stepOne * stepTwo);
        }
      }
    }
    return nonEaten;
  }

  private static boolean isMultiply(int candidate, Set<Integer> oldSet){
    for(int element : oldSet) {
      if(candidate % element == 0){
        return true;
      }
    }
    return false;
  }

  private static int getEatenWithStep(int n, int step){
    return step > n ? 0 : n / step;
  }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).