# figure out Uneaten Leaves algorithm bug

Tags: c++, algorithm, discrete-mathematics

I faced this problem in an interview challenge

> K caterpillars are eating their way through N leaves, each caterpillar
> falls from leaf to leaf in a unique sequence, all caterpillars start
> at a twig at position 0 and falls onto the leaves at position between
> 1 and N. Each caterpillar j has an associated jump number Aj. A
> caterpillar with jump number j eats leaves at positions that are
> multiple of j. It will proceed in the order j, 2j, 3j…. till it
> reaches the end of the leaves and it stops and build its cocoon. Given
> a set A of K elements , we need to determine the number
> of uneaten leaves.
>
> **Constraints:**
>
> 1 <= N <= 10<sup>9</sup>
>
> 1 <= K <= 15
>
> 1 <= A[i] <= 10<sup>9</sup>
>
> **Input format:**
>
> N = No of uneaten leaves.
>
> K = No. of caterpillars.
>
> A = Array of integer.
> jump numbers Output:
>
> The integer nu. Of uneaten leaves
>
> **Sample Input:**
>
> `10`
> `3` 
> `2` 
> `4` 
> `5`
>
> **Output:**
>
> `4`
>
> **Explanation:**
>
> [2, 4, 5] is the 3-member set of jump numbers. All leaves which are multiple of 2, 4, and 5 are eaten. Only 4 leaves which are numbered 1,3,7,9 are left.

the naive approach for solving this question is have a *Boolean* array of all N numbers, and iterate over every caterpillar and remember the eaten leaves by it.

```
int uneatenusingNaive(int N, vector<int> A)
{
    int eaten = 0;
    vector<bool>seen(N+1, false);
    for (int i = 0; i < A.size(); i++)
    {
        long Ai = A[i];
        long j = A[i];
        while (j <= N && j>0)
        {
            if (!seen[j])
            {
                seen[j] = true;
                eaten++;
            }
            j += Ai;
        }
    }
    return N - eaten;
}
```

this approach passed 8 out of 10 test cases and give wrong answer for 2 cases.

another approach using [Inclusion Exclusion principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle%22Inclusion%20Exclusion%20principle%22), explanation for it can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27248327/caterpillars-and-leaves-can-we-do-better-than-onc) and [here](http://www.iarcs.org.in/inoi/contests/sep2004/Advanced-2-solution.php) 
below is my code for the second approach

```
 int gcd(int a, int b)
    {
        if (b == 0)
            return a;
        return gcd(b, a%b);
    }
    int lcm(int i, int j)
    {
        return i*j / gcd(i, j);
    }
    
    vector<vector<int>> mixStr(vector<vector<int>> & mix, vector<int>& A, unordered_map<int, int> & maxStart)
    {
        vector<vector<int>> res;
        if (mix.size() == 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < A.size(); i++)
            {
                vector<int> tmp;
                tmp.push_back(A[i]);
                res.push_back(tmp);
            }
            return res;
        }
        
        
        for (int i = 0; i<mix.size(); i++)
        {
            int currSlotSize = mix[i].size();
            int currSlotMax = mix[i][currSlotSize - 1];
            
            for (int j = maxStart[currSlotMax]; j < A.size(); j++)
            {
                vector<int> tmp(mix[i]);
                tmp.push_back(A[j]);
                res.push_back(tmp);
            }
        }
        return res;
    }
    int uneatenLeavs(int N, int k, vector<int> A)
    {
        int i = 0;
        vector<vector<int>> mix;
        bool sign = true;
        int res = N;
        sort(A.begin(), A.end());
        unordered_map<int,int> maxStart;
        for (int i = 0; i < A.size(); i++)
        {
            maxStart[A[i]] = i + 1;
        }
        int eaten = 0;
        
    
        while (mix.size() != 1)
        {   
            
            mix = mixStr(mix, A, maxStart);
            for (int j = 0; j < mix.size(); j++)
            {
                int _lcm = mix[j][0];
                for (int s = 1; s < mix[j].size(); s++)
                {
                    _lcm = lcm(mix[j][s], _lcm);
                }
                if (sign)
                {
                    res -= N / _lcm;
                }
                else
                {
                    res += N / _lcm;
                }
            }
            sign = !sign;
            i++;
        }
        return res;
    }
```

this approach passed only one 1/10 test case. and for the rest of test cases time limit exceeded and wrong answer. 
 
**Question:** 
What am I missing in first or second approach to be 100% correct.

Comment: You mention that the first approach passes 8/10. Could you provide the examples it succeeds/fails?

Comment: @shapiroyaacov unfortunately the test cases are hidden.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using Inclusion-Exclusion theorem is correct approach, however, your implementation seems to be too slow. We can use bitmasking technique to obtain a **O(K*2^K)** time complexity.

Take a look at this:

```
long result = 0;

for(int i = 1; i < 1 << K; i++){
     long lcm = 1;
     for(int j = 0; j < K; j++)
        if(((1<<j) & i) != 0) //if bit j is set, compute new LCM after including A[j]
           lcm *= A[j]/gcd(lcm, A[j]);
     if(number of bit set in i is odd)
        result += N/lcm;
     else
        result -= N/lcm; 
}
```

For your first approach, an **O(N*K)** time complexity algorithm, with N = 10^9 and K = 15, it will be too slow, and can cause memory limit exceed/time limit exceed.

Notice that `lcm` can be larger than N, so, additional check is needed.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but i don't quite understand this line  lcm*= lcm*A[j]/gcd(lcm, A[j]);
and for first approach it gives wrong answer. if it was memory or time limit, the online judge will give it another message.

Comment: @MahmoudEmam It is to calculate the least common multiple of subset of A, so we know that `lcm of (a,b) = a*b / gcd(a,b)` and `lcm(a, b , c) = lcm(lcm(a,b), c)`, so to calculate `lcm of (a, b, c, d ...) = lcm(lcm(lcm(a, b), c) , d)...`

Comment: @MahmoudEmam your first approach looks ok, so, it may be because of some language specific problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot I got it, and it is very interesting trick to use bits for generating power set.

Comment: i think lcm*= lcm*A[j]/gcd(lcm, A[j]); should be lcm *= A[j]/gcd(lcm, A[j]); or lcm = lcm* A[j]/gcd(lcm, A[j]);